# Intellij .jar from module with dependencies -> error: (java.util.zip.ZipException) invalid entry crc-32

Tags: intellij-idea, jar

I have an IntelliJ IDEA Java Project and I want to create a .jar file

[image]

I choose the Main Class and say that the JAR files from libary:

[image]

I have a /lib folder containing some .jar file which my application uses.
I added them to the project by 
[image]

If I now make the project and then the .jar file I get the following error message ( Without creating the .jar file the application works.

```
Error:Internal error: (java.util.zip.ZipException) invalid entry crc-32 (expected 0x5a5ec5c7 but got 0x16e4e973)
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry crc-32 (expected 0x5a5ec5c7 but got 0x16e4e973)
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.closeEntry(ZipOutputStream.java:296)
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.finish(ZipOutputStream.java:361)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.close(DeflaterOutputStream.java:238)
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.close(ZipOutputStream.java:378)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.artifacts.impl.JarsBuilder.buildJar(JarsBuilder.java:212)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.artifacts.impl.JarsBuilder.buildJars(JarsBuilder.java:88)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.artifacts.IncArtifactBuilder.build(IncArtifactBuilder.java:166)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.artifacts.IncArtifactBuilder.build(IncArtifactBuilder.java:50)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTarget(IncProjectBuilder.java:906)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:887)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:945)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:840)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:663)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:370)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:191)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:293)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:124)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:242)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making an **artifact**. In Intellij 14.1.3:

File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts -> (red) Plus sign -> JAR

From "Available elements" select your compile output folder. On image called "'swingDemo' compile output"

[image: Artifact view]

If you have dependencies (like here I add gson:2.3.1 to my jar), download them into your /lib folder and add them with the (blue) plus sign -> Extracted Directory -> chose the dependency from your /lib folder.

[image: Extracted resource]
[image]

That will basically put your dependency into one JAR.